# Is it ok to use fixed gear threads for a freewheel?

Tags: fixed-gear, single-speed, flip-flop-hub

I have a fixed/fixed flip-flop hub and the lockring threads are stripped out on one side. Would I be ok to just thread a single-speed freewheel on that side and use it as a fixed/free hub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the thread fits, there would be no problem.

The nature of the mechanical stresses over the hub during traction would be identical (only there would not be the backpedal component, but that means less stress, not more).

Comment: I have seen a quality freewheel (White Industries) strip the threads on the fixed side of a quality flip-flop hub (Paul), however this was on a wheel used for Hardcourt bike polo, where explosive acceleration, good traction and low gearing (about 40 gear inches) combine to apply a lot of torque through the threads. Still not a common failure though.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it will work without issue.

Humans would have to generate far more torque than we are capable of to actually pull the threads off of the hub. If you think about it, if it's enough threads for a track cog then there's no reason it wouldn't be enough for a freewheel. Due to the smaller amount of engagement on a fixed thread the mechanical stresses would be slightly different but once again not enough to matter for our power output.

I can tell you that I've run a couple of setups like this for years, as have many others, with no issue on any of them related to the topic at hand.